# Div vertical position based on window width

Tags: css, html, resize, position

I have an image that I have set to resize to 100% of the window width.

I have a div of text that I want to position over a certain part of that image (so it's readable).

Because the height of the image changes with the width, I need to the div of text to move up and down so that it stays over a particular portion of the image.

Is there a way to adjust the vertical positioning of the div automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: I pretty sure I know what you are going for but can you show something that displays the text exactly where you want it on the image?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the html is:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="image"><img src="abc.png" /></div>
 <div id="text">some text</div>
</div>
```

You'll add following jquery script to put the text always inside the image layer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  putInsideImage();
});
function putInsideImage(){
 var h = $("#image").innerHeight();
 var w = $("#image").innerWidth();
 $("#text").css({"margin-top":-(h/2) + "px", "margin-left": (w/2) + "px"});
}
```

Comment: That places the text according to the height of the image div, but it means I need to set the height of the image div manually. The height of the image div needs to be flexible to accomadate the scaling image.

Comment: @user199846 - Notice that I'm using `innerWidth()` and `innerHeight()` means it will calculate the height/width of the div at runtime based on the image's width/height. You don't have to set it anywhere.

Comment: I just can't seem to get it to stick to the middle of the image. Not sure where I'm going wrong, but I'm guessing it might have to do with jquery.imagefit.js I'm using.

Comment: You can see what I'm working with here: http://marckimmel.com/projects/test/textposition/.

Maybe you can see where I'm going wrong.